# Flutter Animated Digit Widget always animates on rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I am using the [animated_digit](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_digit) in my app and it is working fine, but how can I stop it from rebuilding/animating when the widget `rebuilds`?

[image]

It obviously rebuilds everytime the keyboard appears/disappears. How can I stop that?

This is the code:

```
class AnimatedDigit extends StatefulWidget {
  final int value;
  const AnimatedDigit({super.key, required this.value});

  @override
  State<AnimatedDigit> createState() => _AnimatedDigitState();
}

class _AnimatedDigitState extends State<AnimatedDigit> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedDigitWidget(
      value: widget.value,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
      textStyle: AppTextStyles.recoletaH1Regular,
    );
  }
}
```